# Guidance for upgrading jquery 1.7.2

Tags: jquery

I want to upgrade the jquery on my site from 1.7.2 to 1.12.4 first, then to 3.0.0

I have added the migration plugin as described on jquery site. This hasn't shown any problems in the console, but when I replace the 1.7.2 with 1.12.4 the more/less jquery toggle isn't displaying.

Do you know what is wrong? Thanks

Comment: The toggle event was deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9. https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/. I would think that the migrate plugin would catch that though

Comment: I don't get any warning messages with the migrate plugin.

Comment: Either way the jQuery docs for toggle() tell you about that change.